what are configuration variables and environment variables
I have started learning git from the git book and i couldn't understand any of this, especially the concept of variables.
"Git comes with a tool called git config that lets you get and set configuration variables that control all aspects of how Git looks and operates. These variables can be stored in three different places:
[path]/etc/gitconfig file: Contains values applied to every user on the system and all their repositories. If you pass the option --system to git config, it reads and writes from this file specifically. Because this is a system configuration file, you would need administrative or superuser privilege to make changes to it.
~/.gitconfig or ~/.config/git/config file: Values specific personally to you, the user. You can make Git read and write to this file specifically by passing the --global option, and this affects all of the repositories you work with on your system.
config file in the Git directory (that is, .git/config) of whatever repository you’re currently using: Specific to that single repository. You can force Git to read from and write to this file with the --local option, but that is in fact the default. Unsurprisingly, you need to be located somewhere in a Git repository for this option to work properly.
Each level overrides values in the previous level, so values in .git/config trump those in [path]/etc/gitconfig."
i looked through yt and they have all shown videos of how to configure those variables for npm packages and stuff but i wanna understand what they mean, why do we need them, how do we configure them, i would appreciate any resources or any videos i can learn about this topic from.

The confusion you're having about Git config variables is understandable. They can seem abstract at first, but they're actually quite useful for customizing how you interact with Git. Here's a breakdown to help you grasp the concept:
What are Git config variables?
Think of them like settings for Git. These variables control various aspects of Git's behavior, like your name and email used for commits, preferred text editor, or even color schemes for the command line interface.
Why do we need them?
Personalization: Config variables let you tailor Git to your workflow. For example, you can set your preferred editor to open staged changes, making your commits smoother.
Consistency: By setting your name and email globally, you ensure all your commits have consistent information across projects.
Customization: Want your terminal output to be more visually appealing? Config variables can set color themes for a more pleasant experience.
How do we configure them?
Git provides a command called git config to manage these variables. There are three main scopes for configuration:
System-wide: ([path]/etc/gitconfig): This file affects all users on the system and requires administrator privileges to modify. You'd rarely need to change this directly.
Global (user-specific): (~/.gitconfig or ~/.config/git/config): This file stores settings for your entire user account. Use git config --global to manage these.
Local (repository-specific): (.git/config inside the repository): This file stores configurations specific to that particular repository. Use git config (without any flags) to manage these.
Learning Resources:
Now, while videos about configuring variables for npm packages might not directly translate to Git config, they can offer valuable insight into the concept of managing configurations within tools.
Here are some resources to solidify your understanding:
Official Git Documentation: The Git SCM website has a detailed section on git config: https://git-scm.com/
Interactive Git Tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials (This interactive tutorial offers a hands-on approach to learning Git concepts)
GitKraken - Git Basics: https://www.gitkraken.com/learn/git/tutorials (This website provides a clear explanation of Git basics, including configuration)
Remember, practice is key! Try setting some basic config variables (like your name and email) using the git config command. Experiment with different scopes to understand how they interact. This will solidify your understanding and make Git feel more personalized and efficient.

Very nice, but you answered an off-topic question. No need to worry. Read the https://stackoverflow.com/help about on-topic questions and keep writing good answers like this. Your view of explaining problems is very helpful (IMHO). Keep posting!
